# Perl regex one liner not working correctly

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'm trying to do the following in a bash script to a file:

Before:

```
{
    "main": "3.3.0",
    "archive":[
        "3.2.2"
    ]
}
```

After:

```
{
    "main": "3.3.1",
    "archive":[
        "3.3.0",
        "3.2.2"
    ]
}
```

using this perl one liner:

```
perl -pi -e "s/\"main\"\: \"(.*?)(\".*)\[/\"main\": \"${version}\2\[\n\t\t\"\1\",/s" "$json"
```

Where `$version` holds the new version number and `$json` is the path to the file.

It seems perl doesn't match, and I can't understand why. Removing the `\[` does match, but I can't see what's wrong with that literal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's a quick closing. This question is about JSON data and not only multiline matching...

Comment: @oliv  Added another close reason: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No doubt these are good resource doc to start with, but for sure doesn't answer OP's question about incrementing version number and moving object to a json array...

Comment: Why it doesn't match: it processes the file line by line, and modifiers won't help since the regex simply always has just one line from the file. Then, `main` and `[` are not on the same line; there is no `main.*[` pattern on any lines.  You'd need to capture and store the version number for the next lines, or read the whole file into a scalar with `-0777`. But I'd recommend to escape many (easy-error-) details using a module, and to avoid syntax (and maintainability) issues by putting this in a script and run that.

Comment: @zdim thanks for the explanation. For some reason I didn’t consider parsing the JSON - sometimes you get your head too tied up in a problem to see the obvious solution. But an explainer of why this didn’t work will help me understand how Perl works in future.

Comment: @Nick You are welcome, let me know if more can help.  Getting drawn in is completely understood. There is a lot that one _can_ do with a regex -- but it also gets tricky very quick, and it is often a blessing when you can do it nicely otherwise; a similar (and stronger) statement goes for a "one-liner."  As soon as you feel like you're cramming more and more into it (a "one-liner" that almost invariably comes with a nasty regex) to make it work it's likely time to step back, open up a file for the script, and reconsider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you can fix your JSON (a trailing comma is not allowed) I'd recommend to process this using a module, and in a script.

An example with [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON), wrapped in a "one"-liner as asked

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -MJSON -0777 -wnE'
    my $hr = decode_json $_; 
    unshift @{$hr->{archive}}, $hr->{main}; 
    $hr->{main} =~ s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.\K([0-9]+)/$1+1/e; 
    path("new_".$ARGV)->spew(encode_json $hr)' 
' data.json
```

The very handy [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) is used to easily dump JSON output. I make the output file name by prefixing `new_` to the input filename (available in [$ARGV  variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$ARGV)), adjust as suitable.

If installing a module is a problem for some reason you can instead simply print the JSON encoded string and redirect the output

```
perl -MJSON -0777 -wnE'
    my $hr = decode_json $_; 
    unshift @{$hr->{archive}}, $hr->{main}; 
    $hr->{main} =~ s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.\K([0-9]+)/$1+1/e; 
    say encode_json $hr 
' data.json > new_data.json
```

These produce the output file with   `{"archive":["3.3.0","3.2.2"],"main":"3.3.1"}`

With the `-0777` [command switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) the whole file is "slurped" into a scalar (`$_`) and `-M...` loads the given module. Then we use `decode_json`, which `JSON` exports by default in its functional interface, to obtain a hashref with data.

The current value of `main` is then added to the beginning of the arrayref in `archive` using [unshift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html), and is then changed by bumping up its release/patch number, using a regex.

Finally the `encode_json`, also exported in `JSON`'s functional interface, is used to  JSON-encode the hashref, what is dumped either with `Path::Tiny` to a file or to STDOUT for redirection.

---

A word on the number of existing JSON modules is in order, prompted by comment by Grinnz.

The [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) linked above will load the [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) module, and if that is not installed then it falls back to the compatible pure-Perl one, [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP). I'd recommend the XS module, which is much faster and proven in wide use.

Another option is [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS#cPanel-fork), the  `JSON::XS` fork with a bug tracker and a list of [bug fixes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS#cPanel-fork). I've happily used both without any issues.

To have these tried in order `Cpanel::` then `::XS` then `::PP`, also with some improvements over `JSON` in how backends are loaded, use [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS).

Note that none of these are in core.

Comment: May I suggest recommending JSON::MaybeXS instead of JSON; neither is core, but JSON does not default to the currently-recommended Cpanel::JSON::XS backend, and adds significant overhead to any backend it uses, whereas JSON::MaybeXS does not have these issues and is largely a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Grinnz Added a comment, thanks for prompting it  I am aware of talk of the missing bug tracker and lack of responsiveness (for ::XS), but I've seen counter-claims as well and without a firm knowledge of the matter (and no first-hand experience) I can't directly recommend to go this way or that.  Thus a generic comment and people can research and make choices.

Comment: What's up with all the -1's on this page?  Nothing posted is any good?

Answer (score 1):

(now that Ihis question has been reopened and I can post an answer..)

Assuming you fix your data so it's valid JSON (Note the invalid trailing comma), this is an easy [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) one-liner:

```
$ jq "{main: \"$version\", archive: [ .main, .archive[] ]}" "$json" > new.json
$ mv -f new.json "$json"
```

Just like with HTML and XML, using regular expressions to try to manipulate JSON is a mistake. Use a more appropriate tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq` to both move the `main` version number to the array `archive` and increment the last digit of the `main` version:

```
jq '.archive += [.main] |
    .main |= (split(".") | .[-1] |= (tonumber+1|tostring) | join("."))' file
```

The operator `+=` adds a new value to the array `archive`.

The operator `|=` assigns a new value to `main`. The last element of the splitted string is incremented by 1 and then reassembled.